# Test Google Analytics on Android devices

Tags: android, testing, google-analytics, automated-tests

Is there an automation test framework to test Google Analytics on Android? Ex. to be sure that correct events are triggered on the particular screen for user action? And that events not sent to Google from places where they are not supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

@Mike You could create a test account with Google Analytics and add that key for test purpose in your project just to verify that your events are tracked properly.After that replace it with your original key.